# Trying to extract strings using regex - Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract a portion from a string in python 2.7 using a regular expression (re module).

The best I can get is

```
res = "{{PakBusPort_somename} 11942 pakbus-port 1}\r\n{{Somename} 5436 CR800-series 2}"
p = re.compile('PakBusPort_')
m = p.findall( res )
```

Which will give me "PakBusPort_". But I also need it to give me the "somename" portion.

Basically I need everything in between { and } that starts with "PakBusPort_". I have tried

`p = re.compile('PakBusPort_.*}}')`

But no results.

I am a bit of a noob with regular expressions so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [71]: p = re.compile(r'{PakBusPort_(.*?)}')

In [72]: p.findall(res)
Out[72]: ['somename']
```

If you also need to include `PakBusPort_`, move the opening parenthesis:

```
In [73]: p = re.compile(r'{(PakBusPort_.*?)}')

In [74]: p.findall(res)
Out[74]: ['PakBusPort_somename']
```

The question mark is needed to make the match *non-greedy*, meaning that it'll stop at the first `}` rather than matching everything till the last one.

Comment: Champion. I needed it to include the "PakBusPort_" portion but changing it to 
`p = re.compile(r'{(PakBusPort_.*?)}')`
Gave me the result I was after.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and don't forget to mark good solutions as Accepted Answer. It helps visitors and rewards the answerer.

Answer (score 0):

You were close, this should give you back a list of tuples matching your regex:

```
res = '{{PakBusPort_somename} 11942 pakbus-port 1}\r\n{{Somename} 5436 CR800-series 2}'
p = re.compile('{(PakBusPort)_([^}]*)}')
m = p.findall( res )
print m

[('PakBusPort', 'somename')]
```